# Zip codes, Geo coding, Joining/relating

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding, zip-codes, flow-map

I have a file of Tennessee zip codes and another excel file including 600,000 origin and destination addresses with zip codes and trip purposes. Since I cannot Geocode all 600,000 addresses, I Geocoded zip codes, and now want to create a flow map with joining/relating these two files together. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.